# multiple input have same name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Here i have two fields such as follows

```
 <div class="left_2 two">

        <select name="abc_type" id="abc_type_2" class="form-control">
          <option value="AB">LSK-AB</option>
          <option value="AC">LSK-AC</option>
          <option value="BC">LSK-BC</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="left_2 one">

        <select name="abc_type" id="abc_type_1" class="form-control">
          <option value="A">LSK-A</option>
          <option value="B">LSK-B</option>
          <option value="C">LSK-C</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

i will be using only one field at a time and the remaining field will be hidden and the problem am always getting the value `A` which is present in second select tag while getting submitted.how can i pass the correct value which i choosed

Comment: Show what you've tried first. And clarify what exactly do you want.

Comment: @Beginner both values is inserting into the same column so i choose this way

Comment: use `select name="abc_type[]"` to get all values with same name

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri what i have done after that  is just passed that value in to the database and  always getting inserted the value as `A`,even though one the field is hidden

Comment: @prakashtank here i will be only one select type and the remaining will be hidden

Comment: jquery will help you do that just add class `hide` to the hidden select input and remove its name

Comment: @user_777 : becuase you gave both select box same name it won't be inserted in diff columns. you need to change the name of both select box. and that's a proper way else you will always get the same value.

Comment: @Beginner how can we remove the name can you please help

Comment: it's up to you, how you are selecting them

Comment: @Beginner now i cleared by going through your logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution what ever field will be hidden add disabled in the input field Check the code below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['abc_type'])){
  echo $_POST['abc_type'];
}


?>
<form action="" method="post">   
 <div class="left_2 two">

        <select name="abc_type" id="abc_type_2" class="form-control">
          <option value="AB">LSK-AB</option>
          <option value="AC">LSK-AC</option>
          <option value="BC">LSK-BC</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="left_2 one">

        <select name="abc_type" id="abc_type_1" class="form-control">
          <option value="A">LSK-A</option>
          <option value="B">LSK-B</option>
          <option value="C">LSK-C</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit"/>
    </form>
```